# Google Appengine(GAE) :: How to prevent Dogpile effect when using GAE memcached?

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached, google-cloud-datastore

I need to cache some costly queries(5sec). I recently came to know about dogpile affect when using memcache. One solution is using locks on cache key-value pair to prevent this effect. Since GAE memcached doesn't support locks on memcached key-values, what is the best practice to prevent dogpile effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what your app is doing, but here are three approaches that can be useful (none is perfect for all scenarios, they each have downsides):

If you can respond to the request with something like 'wait a bit and try again' then setting a flag that represents that into memcache on a miss, before you spend the time re-processing the real value could help (there will still be the possibility of a race between the get and the first set, but it will be much shorter than waiting for the query to be done):

```
value = memcache.get(key)
if value is None:
  memcache.set(key, 'recalculating')
  // do the slow thing
  memcache.set(key, actual_result)

return value
```

Alternatively, if you're setting a lifetime on your cached results, but could cope with clients receiving slightly stale data, then as well as caching your value with a timeout and a key, you cache a copy with no timeout and a different key, then on miss use this copy to re-populate the cache while you re-process a fresh value (again, still the chance of a race between the get/set, and also it's possible the copy will be evicted.):

```
value = memcache.get(key)
if value is None:
  memcache.set(key, cache.get(key+'copy'))
  // do the slow thing
  memcache.set(key, actual_result, 30)
  memcache.set(key+'copy', actual_result)

return value
```

The third is simpler, simply have a backend constantly doing your query and have it update the cache, so that frontend requests are less likely to have to do it. This does mean, though, that the queries are being done regardless of the values being used by anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore it.

Drink the Google Kool-Aid and believe that you won't get significant database thrashing from the simultaneous queries hitting the datastore.  Dogpile effect is transient anyways, and the infrastructure should absorb it.  You just pay for a few more queries.

Unless you actually have enough traffic and it's costing you significant money, it's probably pretty far down on your priorities.

Answer (score 0):

Dogpile effect can be prevented using semaphore lock. If value expired, first process acquires a lock and starts generating new value. All the subsequent requests check if lock is acquired and serve stale content (if so). After new value is generated, lock is released.

Cached values should be given an extended life time, so they’re not physically removed when they expire and they can be still served if there’s a need.

Here's how it works in PHP (should be easy to replicate in Python).

*Get cache value from cache store.*

```php
$value = $this->store->get($key);
```

$value is a value object.

*Check whether cached value expired or not. If not expired, serve it.*

```php
if ($value && !$value->isStale()) {
    return $value->getResult();
}
```

*Otherwise, acquire lock so there’s just one process regenerating new value.*

```php
$lock_acquired = $this->acquireLock($key, $grace_ttl);
```

*If lock cannot be acquired, it means there’s already other process regenerating it, so let’s just serve current (stale) value.*

```php
if (!$lock_acquired) {
    return $value->getResult();
}
```

*Otherwise (lock has been acquired), regenerate new value.*

```php
$result = ...
```

*Save regenerated value in cache store. Add grace period, so stale result might be served if needed by other processes.*

```php
$expiration_timestamp = time() + $ttl;
$value = new Value($result, $expiration_timestamp);

$real_ttl = $ttl + $grace_ttl;
$this->store->set($key, $value, $real_ttl);
```

*Release lock.*

```php
$this->releaseLock($key);
```

Full PHP implementation: https://github.com/sobstel/metaphore/blob/master/src/Cache.php. You can also try MintCache: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/155/.